# Trouble implementing a very simple mass flow source

Tags: connector, modelica, dymola

I am currently learning Modelica by trying some very simple examples. I have defined a connector `Incompressible` for an incompressible fluid like this:

```
connector Incompressible
  flow Modelica.SIunits.VolumeFlowRate V_dot;
  Modelica.SIunits.SpecificEnthalpy h;
  Modelica.SIunits.Pressure p;
end Incompressible;
```

I now wish to define a mass or volume flow source:

```
model Source_incompressible
  parameter Modelica.SIunits.VolumeFlowRate V_dot;
  parameter Modelica.SIunits.Temperature T;
  parameter Modelica.SIunits.Pressure p;
  Incompressible outlet;
equation 
  outlet.V_dot = V_dot;
  outlet.h = enthalpyWaterIncompressible(T);  // quick'n'dirty enthalpy function
  outlet.p = p;
end Source_incompressible;
```

However, when checking `Source_incompressible`, I get this:

```
The problem is structurally singular for the element type Real.
The number of scalar Real unknown elements are 3.
The number of scalar Real equation elements are 4.
```

I am at a loss here. Clearly, there are three equations in the model - where does the fourth equation come from?

Thanks a lot for any insight.

Answer (score 3):

Dominic,

There are a couple of issues going on here.  As Martin points out, the connector is unbalanced (you don't have matching "through" and "across" pairs in that connector).  For fluid systems, this is acceptable.  However, intensive fluid properties (e.g., enthalpy) have to be marked as so-called "stream" variables.

This topic is, admittedly, pretty complicated.  I'm planning on adding an advanced chapter to my [online Modelica book](http://book.xogeny.com/) on this topic but I haven't had the time yet.  In the meantime, I would suggest you have a look at the `Modelica.Fluid` library and/or [this presentation](http://staff.polito.it/roberto.zanino/sub1/teach_files/modelica_minicourse/06%20-%20Modelica.Fluid.pdf) by one of its authors, Francesco Casella.

Comment: Thanks, Michael and @sjoelund.se! I am still not quite clear about the merits of a "balanced" or "physical" connector (these terms are synonymous, right?). Why is it desirable to have matching pairs of flow and potential variables? In my case, one would have to add an enthalpy flow variable `H_dot` which is a product of the other connection variables - a situation one would like to avoid.

Another thing I am confused about is why creating an _instance_ of a connector in a model (no `connect()`) generates an equation for each flow variable. Is this done to cope with unconnected connectors?

Comment: OK, balanced and physical are slightly different.  A physical connector is one that formulates equations based on conservation principles (think Kirchoff's voltage and current laws).  A balanced MODEL is one that is sure to have the correct number of equations.  You can find [a discussion of balanced models](http://book.xogeny.com/components/components/component_models/#balanced-components) in my book.

Comment: Michael, just for the record, I was specifically asking about balanced _connectors_, not the general concept of balanced models. You used the term "unbalanced connector", but I was unable find a formal definition thereof, hence my question. (Maybe shortening down my reply to 600 characters took its toll. ;) Also, again for the record, I have spent hours with your online book as well as your 2001 paperback. Your efforts are much appreciated!)

Answer (score 1):

That connector is not a physical connector. You need one flow variable for each potential variable. This is the OpenModelica error message if it helps a little:

```
Warning: Connector .Incompressible is not balanced: The number of potential variables (2) is not equal to the number of flow variables (1).
Error: Too many equations, over-determined system. The model has 4 equation(s) and 3 variable(s).
Error: Internal error Found Equation without time dependent variables outlet.V_dot = V_dot
```

This is because the unconnected connector will generate one equation for the flow:

```
outlet.V_dot = 0.0;
```

This means outlet.V_dot is replaced in:

```
outlet.V_dot = V_dot;
```

And you get:

```
0.0 = V_dot;
```

But V_dot is a parameter and can not be assigned to in an equation section (needs an initial equation if the parameter has fixed=false, or a binding equation in the default case).