# Trouble balancing a simple power flow model in modelica

Tags: modelica

I try to set up a simple model with electrical or thermal power flows between sources and sinks. 
I seem to have the same problem as treated in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23811595/trouble-implementing-a-very-simple-mass-flow-source) although I used only one pair of flow and potential variables in my connector:

```
connector PowerPortE
  flow SI.Power P;
  SI.Voltage v "Dummy potential-variable to balance flow-variable P";
end PowerPortE;
```

A simple example with a signal responsed power sink looks like this:

```
model PowerSinkE
  SimplePowerSystem.PowerPortE Port;
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput P(unit = "W");
  SI.Voltage v(start = 230);
equation
  Port.P = P;
  Port.v = v;
end PowerSinkE;

model Test
  SimplePowerSystem.PowerSinkE Verbraucher ;
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Sine sine1(freqHz = 50) ;
equation
  connect(sine1.y,Verbraucher.P);
end Test;
```

Checking `PowerSinkE` goes well, but when trying to simulate, I get the following errors:

```
Internal error pre-optimization module removeSimpleEquations failed.

Internal error Found Equation without time dependent variables Verbraucher.Port.P = const.k

An independent subset of the model has imbalanced number of equations (1) and variables (2).
variables:
Verbraucher.v
Verbraucher.Port.v
equations:
1 : Verbraucher.Port.v = Verbraucher.v

An independent subset of the model has imbalanced number of equations (4) and variables (3).
variables:
sine1.y
Verbraucher.P
Verbraucher.Port.P
equations:
1 : Verbraucher.Port.P = Verbraucher.P
2 : sine1.y = sine1.offset + (if time < sine1.startTime then 0.0 else sine1.amplitude * sin(6.283185307179586 * sine1.freqHz * (time - sine1.startTime) + sine1.phase))
3 : Verbraucher.Port.P = 0.0
4 : Verbraucher.P = sine1.y
```

Initially I wanted to leave the variable `v` completely out of the model (though I had to leave it in the connector to be balanced) but this didn't work out either:

```
Model is structurally singular, error found sorting equations
 1: 0.0 = sine1.offset + (if time < sine1.startTime then 0.0 else sine1.amplitude * sin(6.283185307179586 * sine1.freqHz * (time - sine1.startTime) + sine1.phase));
 for variables
 Verbraucher.Port.v(1)
```

The problem seems to be that I need the flow variable power but don't have a corresponding potential variable. I am running out of ideas how to fix this, so thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial thought is that port in the consumer is unconnected. This adds the equation `consumer.port.P = 0.0`. But what you really need is an equation for the voltage in the port.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! What equation for the voltage would you suggest? And if the unconnected port should be an issue, why isn't it a problem if one uses for example the `PrescribedTemperature` from the modelica standard library and leaves it unconnected? I tried this out earlier to exclude this possible issue and it worked just fine.

Comment: It's working now! Thanks @sjoelund.se. What I did is, I set my dummy voltage to a dummy value in the equation part, `v=0;` for example. This has to be done in only one element of the grid (power source or sink). And with the consumer connected to a source the thing is balanced and simulates!

Comment: I'll have to add: Obviously it is no problem leaving the `PrescribedTemperature` unconnected as mentioned above because here the input signal is connected to a potential variable (T) and not a conserved quantity like energy or mass flow. As a result the issue that a flow goes in (the signal) and nothing goes out (unconnected) doesn't appear.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you try to use a connector in this case? If you don't need the "pyhsical meaning" of flow and potential variables inside the connector, you just can use real inputs and outputs to handle signals.

```
package SimplePowerSystem
 model PowerSinkE
  import SI = Modelica.SIunits;
  SI.Power P;
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput P_in(unit="W");
 equation
  P = P_in;
 end PowerSinkE;
 model Test
  SimplePowerSystem.PowerSinkE Verbraucher;
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Sine sine1(freqHz = 50);
 equation
  connect(sine1.y, Verbraucher.P_in);
 end Test;
end SimplePowerSystem;
```

Comment: I agree.  The fundamental design decision here is whether this is meant to be a physical model or simply a data flow model.  If you simply want to compute the value of a signal as it flows through, then Florian's solution is fine.  BUT, you will not (easily) get the "reaction" of your physical system in this way.  So it is very easy to miss effects in the response of the system.

Comment: I guess this would be a solution, thank you. Although I still a have a little bit of a problem with that "physical model" approach. I would say that balancing power or energy flows, as based on the first law of thermodynamics, is a straight physics-based task (and energy flows are not signals). So I would consider this solution a work-around. I still don't understand why it should be not possible to deal with this in modelica in a physical and not a signal representation. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use voltage and **current** on your electrical connector and you need an electrical ground.  I suggest you have a look at [Modelica by Example](http://book.xogeny.com) for more about both electrical and thermal component modeling.

Comment: Thanks Michael but since I don't have any current or voltage data for the model, I don't want to simulate an electrical circuit. As noted I had to introduce the voltage as a dummy in order to balance the connector. What I have is only power/energy data which I intent to singal-in into such sinks or sources respectively. Isn't it possible to model a such simple power flows exchanging network with modelica? This model is meant to be a simple data-fed part of a power grid where other, by physical relations built models shall be integrated in order to simulate the reactions of the whole grid.